# js - Closure Compiler and UMD

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, umd

I have some code with a UMD pattern like this:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {        
        define([], factory);
    } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
        module.exports = factory();
    } else {
        root.returnExports = factory();
  }
}(this, function () {
    function sum(a, b)
    {
      return a + b;
    }

    return { sum: sum};
}));

$('body').text(returnExports.sum(32,3));
```

And I want to compile this code with the Google Closure Compiler with the `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` flag. I'm not allowed to change to code above. When I compile this code, the Closure Compiler doesn't recognize that `root.returnExports` equals `window.returnExports` and compiles the code into this:

```
function a() {
    return {
        b: function(b, c) {
            return b + c
        }
    }
}
"function" === typeof define && define.c ? define([], a) : "object" === typeof module && module.a ? module.a = a() : a();
$("body").text(returnExports.b(32, 3));
```

which of course throws an error as `returnExports`(line 9) is not defined. The jQuery function `$('body').text(...);` is declared in an extern file, so that's not the problem.

I saw there was another question about Closure Compiler and UMD pattern: [Google closure compiler and UMD pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847332/google-closure-compiler-and-umd-pattern) , but that didn't help me.

How can I tell the Closure Compiler that `root.returnExports` equals `window.returnExports`?

NOTE:

I want `returnExports` to be renamed to something like `a` or `b`, instead of keeping it's name.

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847332/google-closure-compiler-and-umd-pattern. Why didn't that answer help you?

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth Because the code still compiled to the code in my question, which is not what I wanted